# Return nodes containing property values matching substrings in a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a database with nodes having property "name" with values among the list "first_1", "first_2", "second_1", "second_2", "third_1", "third_2" (each node has only one value among these) and I want to return the nodes having the property "name" with values containing the substring "first" or "second". So the query should return all the nodes with "name" property containing either "first_1" or  "first_2" or "second_1" and so on but not the ones containing "third_*". What should be the ideal Cypher query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this Cypher using `any()` function and `starts with`:

```
with ['first', 'second'] as list
match (n)
where any (item in list where n.name starts with item)
return n
```

Comment: yeah, that is a solution, but I wanted it to generalize and so I mentioned a list that could be sent as a parameter, if the list contained multiple of these values like extending to fourth_1 and so on and I wanted to only return nodes that matched a chosen set of strings. I was trying to see whether I could use a combination of ANY, CONTAINS and FOREACH.

Comment: @soumajyoti_sarkar hi, take a look in my edit. Thanks!